# How do I find out from which fonts windows is pulling substitute glyphs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts

When a given font does not provide a glyph for a unicode character, windows pulls glyphs from a font which does provide it (see screenshot showing charmap and text editor displaying glyphs missing from calluna; the missing glyphs are (not) shown in the pdf visible in the same document. Fontforge also reveals that the glyphs are indeed not in that font).

How can I work out from which font windows is pulling the substitute glyph? (I'm using windows 7)[image]

Comment: Windows doesn't do it;  the program you're using takes care of that, and the handling varies with the program. So it may help if you're more specific about your concern, i.e. what program has you concerned?  For example, the font substitution mechanism in Acrobat is well known, whereas a browser will most often display question marks for the characters that aren't in the current font face & code page. It's also not ensured that when you cut&paste from charmap, you're bringing along the font; that too depends on the program.

Comment: @Debra That's simply not correct. The same glyph substitution is made across windows applications. I think you have misunderstood the question. There are two separate behaviours: (1) deployment of a missing character marker (shown in the graphic as a black box containing a cross); and (2) substitution of the corresponding glyph from another font. In case you don't believe this is a real thing, look at the graphic: Charmap and TeXworks both substitute the same glyphs in the same way, but the PDF consistently displays the font's the missing character character.